# How to access the text inside a TextInput without having the value prop defined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

**I want to create a form without using useState to control the inputs because I only need the inputs values when the user presses the button, so I want to access/know the input value at that time only. I also think that updating the screen after each text input is not a good practice.**

Let's assume that we have the following structure:

```
const Home = () => {
  // const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(""); => I want to avoid that
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        ref={inputRef}
        // value={inputValue} => I want to avoid that
        // onChangeText={(text) => setInputValue(text)} => I want to avoid that
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

We all know that when we have one TextInput on screen, we can type in it, without specifying the **value** prop and **onChangeText**, that we would normally use useState for that.

What I want to do is simply access the text that was input, and I would use a ref for that using **useRef** hook, but the problem is that using useRef I have access to TextInput props but the value is undefined because I am not specifying that. Am I missing something or there is no way to do that without using a useState for defining a **value** and **onChangeText**?

Comment: ref.current.value doesnt work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextInput` by nature is a controlled component.

However, to reach the behavior you need, you can use `onChangeText` to update the value wanted at the end:

```
<TextInput
  ref={inputRef}
  onChangeText={text => {
    if(inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.value = text;
    }
  }}
/>
```

I recommend applying best practices recommended for the component, or checking form libraries like `react-hook-form`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but using Typescript is a bit different, and I answered my own question to share that with everyone. Again, thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: @JancerLima you're welcome, I edited the answer to solve the ts issue which is also a better way to handle it

Comment: Yes, it works, the thing is that if I initialize the ref using the type TextInput, inputRef.current.value would not work, instead we should access inputRef.current.context to store the value. Could you please let it clear in your answer as well? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Majed Badawi answer I could find the following solution.

```
const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
<TextInput
  ref={inputRef}
  onChangeText={(text) => (inputRef!.current!.context = text)}
/>
```

The `!.` operator will make sure that nothing is `null`, and the `context` of the `TextInput` is a readable property that you can set and read values.